# Insert Into with PDO not working

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to get this to work for the last hour. I've checked all links and that the right table is being referenced. I removed the if statement from documents.php and checked, but nothing is inserting the data in to the table. I also checked the error log and I am not receiving any errors.

index.php

```
<div class="content">
<?php if (Session::get('user_logged_in') == true AND $admin == 1):?>
<form action="../processes/documents.php" method="post" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned">
    <legend>Add Document</legend>
      <fieldset>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
              <input type="text" name="documentnumber" placeholder="Document Number">
              </div>                                
              <div class="pure-control-group">  
              <input type="text" name="documentdate" placeholder="Document Date">
              </div>
              <div class="pure-control-group">
              <input type="text" name="expirationdate" placeholder="Document Expiration Date">  
              </div>
              <div class="pure-control-group">  
              <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description">
              </div>                            
              <div class="pure-control-group">  
              <select name="artistname">
                  <?php
                      $con=mysqli_connect("$hostname","$username","$password","saintfiv_artists");
                      if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
                        {
                        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                        }

                      $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM artists ORDER BY `artistname`");

                       while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
                        {
                        echo '<option value="' . $row2['artistname'] . '">' . $row2['artistname'] . '</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
              </select>
              </div>
              <div class="pure-control-group">
              <select name="artwork">';
                  <?php
                      $dir    = '../documents/';
                      $files = scandir($dir);
                      foreach ($files as $filename) {
                          if ($filename != '.' AND $filename != ".."){
                          echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
                          }
                      }
                  ?>
              </select> 
              </div>                            
              <div class="pure-control-group">              
              <button type="submit" name="adddocument" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Add</button>
              </div>
      </fieldset>
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

documents.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['adddocument'])) {
include_once('../config/mysql.php');

$document_number = $_POST['documentnumber'];
$document_date = $_POST['documentdate'];
$document_expiration_date = $_POST['expirationdate'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$artist_name = $_POST['artistname'];
$document_name = $_POST['documentname'];

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=saintfiv_artists", $username, $password);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO documents(`document_number`, `document_date`, `document_expiration_date`, `description`, `artist_name`, `document_name`) VALUES (:document_number, :document_date, :document_expiration_date, :description, :artist_name, :document_name)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':document_number', $document_number, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':document_date', $document_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':document_expiration_date', $document_expiration_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':artist_name', $artist_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':document_name', $document_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

header("Location: http://www.saint57records.com/artistreports/documents/index");
?>
```

Comment: Q: Why are you using `mysqli_` API for `index.php` and PDO for the other?

Comment: Add `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. Plus, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, since you're not checking for potential errors.

Comment: It's because I haven't figured out how to use the select query yet with PDO, I've figured out insert, update, and delete so far.

Comment: `<button>` is not a POST element, that's why nothing is being executed; your conditional statement is based on it. Change your button to `<input type="submit" name="adddocument" value="Submit">` - having error reporting set, would have signaled `Undefined index adddocument`

Comment: Fred, your error reporting suggestion helped me find my problem. Please add your comment as the answer.

Comment: It has been done Michael, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Fred, your error reporting suggestion helped me find my problem. Please add your comment as the answer. "*

As requested by the OP, comment to answer to close the question.

Add:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

right after the connection is opened.

Plus, add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

see if it yields anything, since you're not checking for potential errors.